# 128 bits hierarchical carry look-ahead adder in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

Hi I want to implement an 128 bits hierarchical carry look ahead adder but I don't know how to use levels in my implementation, in fact i don't know how to write the code. I write my code for 16 bits adder but i should use 4-bits blocks and combine them in levels. I almost know that I need 32 numbers of 4-bits blocks in level 1 and 8 numbers in level 2 and so on. However my code should be run for 128 to 256 bits operands but i don't know how to do this. please help me

Answer (score 0):

if you already have 4bit adder, you should implement the hierarchical adder
with for generate statement like this:

```
    library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

    entity carry_leveled is
        generic(c_word_length : integer := 128;
                c_adder_count : integer := c_word_length / 4 --count of adder entities to generate
        );
        port(
            clk_i : in  std_logic;
            rst_i : in  std_logic;
            x_i   : in  std_logic_vector(c_word_length - 1 downto 0);
            y_i   : in  std_logic_vector(c_word_length - 1 downto 0);
            sum_o : out std_logic_vector(c_word_length - 1 downto 0)
        );
    end entity carry_leveled;

    architecture RTL of carry_leveled is
        component carry_lookahead_adder
            port(
                clk_i     : in  std_logic;
                rst_i     : in  std_logic;
                x_i       : in  std_logic_vector(c_word_length - 1 downto 0);
                y_i       : in  std_logic_vector(c_word_length - 1 downto 0);
                carry_i   : in  std_logic;
                carry_out : out std_logic;
                sum_o     : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
            );
        end component;
        signal carry_vector : std_logic_vector(c_adder_count - 1 downto 0);
        signal sum          : std_logic_vector(c_word_length - 1 downto 0);
    begin

        sum_o <= sum;

        carry_lookahead_adder_inst_0 : component carry_lookahead_adder
            port map(clk_i     => clk_i,
                     rst_i     => rst_i,
                     x_i       => x_i(c_adder_count - 1 downto 0),
                     y_i       => y_i(c_adder_count - 1 downto 0),
                     carry_i   => '0',
                     carry_out => carry_vector(0),
                     sum_o     => sum(c_adder_count - 1 downto 0));

        carry_look_adder_generate : for i in 1 to c_adder_count - 1 generate
            carry_lookahead_adder_inst_i : component carry_lookahead_adder
                port map(clk_i     => clk_i,
                         rst_i     => rst_i,
                         x_i       => x_i((i + 1) * c_adder_count - 1 downto i * c_adder_count),
                         y_i       => y_i((i + 1) * c_adder_count - 1 downto i * c_adder_count),
                         carry_i   => carry_vector(i - 1),
                         carry_out => carry_vector(i),
                         sum_o     => sum((i + 1) * c_adder_count - 1 downto i * c_adder_count)
                );
        end generate carry_look_adder_generate;

    end architecture RTL;
```

hope i could help you

Answer (score 0):

it is easier to implement in behavioral modeling language, see the following tutorial for 16 bit and just replace the numbers for 128 bits

[16 bit carry look ahead adder vhdl code](http://appliedelectronicsengineering.blogspot.com/2015/05/16-bit-carry-look-ahead-adder-vhdl-code.html)

Comment: Could you expand on your answer to guard against the link going dead/being blocked by firewall, etc. please? An answer is only as good as its plain text. Many thanks.